# Splitting multiple string columns and rename the new columns adequately- R

Tags: r, string, loops, split

I have a data frame with a large number of string columns.
Each of those columns consists of strings with three parts which I would like split. So in the end the total number of string columns would triple.
When doing that I would additionally like to directly name the new columns by attaching certain predefined strings to their original column name.

As a simplified example

```
test_frame<-tibble(x=c("a1!","b2@","c3$"), y=c("A1$","G2%", NA))

x       y
a1!    A1$
b2@    G2%  
c3$    NA
```

should become something like

```
x_letter   x_number   x_sign    y_letter    y_number    y_sign
a          1          !         A           1           $      
b          2          @         G           2           %
c          3          $         NA          NA          NA
```

The order of the elements within the string is always the same.

The real data frame has over 100 string columns that all can be split into they three parts using a separator. The only exception might be rows where a string is missing.
I've looked into combinations of str_split_fixed(), strsplit() and separate() and apply functions but couldn't figure out how to directly name the columns while also looping over the columns.

What would be a simple approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you need, not the cleanest solution but simple

```r
library(tidyverse)

test_frame<-tibble(x=c("a1!","b2@","c3$"), y=c("A1$","G2%", NA))


pipe_to_do <- . %>%
  str_split_fixed(string = .,pattern = "(?<=.)",n = 3) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  rename(letter = V1,
         number = V2,
         sign = V3)

xx <- test_frame %>%
  summarise(across(everything(),.fns = pipe_to_do))
#> Warning: The `x` argument of `as_tibble.matrix()` must have unique column names if `.name_repair` is omitted as of tibble 2.0.0.
#> Using compatibility `.name_repair`.
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_warnings()` to see where this warning was generated.


names_xx <- names(xx)

combine_names <- function(df,name) {
  str_c(name,"_",df)
}

combine_names_func <- function(df,name){
  df %>% 
    rename_with(.fn = ~ combine_names(.x,name))
}

map2(xx,names_xx,combine_names_func) %>% 
  reduce(bind_cols)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>   x_letter x_number x_sign y_letter y_number y_sign
#>   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>  <chr>    <chr>    <chr> 
#> 1 a        1        !      "A"      "1"      "$"   
#> 2 b        2        @      "G"      "2"      "%"   
#> 3 c        3        $      ""       ""       ""
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_extract`:

```
library(stringr)
df <- data.frame(
  x_letter = str_extract(test_frame$x,"^[a-z]"),
  x_number = str_extract(test_frame$x,"(?<=^[a-z])[0-9]"),
  x_sign = str_extract(test_frame$x,".$"),
  y_letter = str_extract(test_frame$y,"^[A-Z]"),
  y_number = str_extract(test_frame$y,"(?<=^[A-Z])[0-9]"),
  y_sign = str_extract(test_frame$y,".$")
)
```

Result:

```
df
  x_letter x_number x_sign y_letter y_number y_sign
1        a        1      !        A        1      $
2        b        2      @        G        2      %
3        c        3      $     <NA>     <NA>   <NA>
```