# How to use numbers separated by comma as numeric variables

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with survey responses from Qualtrics and analysing the data in R.

15 of questions are multiple choice in which a person can choose more than one choice (For example, a person who picked choices 1, 3 and 4 has output that looks like "1,3,4").
Let's say I have 4 questions (and not 15): social, emotional, cognitive and family.   If a person picked 1,2 and 4 in social, the output will be "1,2,4" and if he picked only "2" for family, the output will be "2". See example database below:

| gender | social | emotional | cognitive | family |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1,2,4 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 3,4 | 4 | 1,2,4 |
| 1 | 3,4 | 1,3 | 1,2,3 | 1 |

Each number in the columns social/emotional/cognitive/family represents a category. If the respondent ticked "1", I have an positive answer for that category and if he did not tick it, I have a negative answer for that category. Therefore, each number in these columns is actually a binary response (positive/negative).

Therefore, to be able to analyse the data (chi square), I want the dataframe to look like this:

| gender | social1 | social2 | social3 | social4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | yes | no | yes | yes |
| 2 | yes | yes | no | no |
| 1 | no | no | yes | no |

Is there a function or series of functions that will let me do that?

Note that I have 15 questions (i.e., 15 columns) like this one, so I'd prefer if I could do it on the entire dataframe and not only on one question.

I've tried doing this (for each column):

```
data<- read.csv("data.csv")
social.data<- data.frame(Sex=c(data$gender),
                       social=c(data$social),
                       str_split_fixed(data$social, ',', 3))
```

R gives me the numbers in separate columns...
From there I couldn't figure out what to do to get to the desired dataframe I described above?

Answer (score 1):

First, use `str_split()` to split the comma separated strings into a list of numbers.  Then, you could map over the known response values to create the binary variables.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
dat <- data.frame(
  gender = c(1,2,1), 
  social = c("1", "2", "3,4"), 
  emotional = c("1,2,4", "3,4", "1,3"), 
  cognitive = c("3", "4", "1,2,3"), 
  family=c("2", "1,2,4", "1")
)
purrr::map(1:4, \(i){
  dat %>% 
    mutate(across(social:family,  ~purrr::map(str_split(.x, ","), as.numeric))) %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    transmute(across(social:family,  ~+(i %in% .x), .names = paste0("{.col}", i)))}) %>% 
    bind_cols() %>% 
    bind_cols(dat,.)
#>   gender social emotional cognitive family social1 emotional1 cognitive1
#> 1      1      1     1,2,4         3      2       1          1          0
#> 2      2      2       3,4         4  1,2,4       0          0          0
#> 3      1    3,4       1,3     1,2,3      1       0          1          1
#>   family1 social2 emotional2 cognitive2 family2 social3 emotional3 cognitive3
#> 1       0       0          1          0       1       0          0          1
#> 2       1       1          0          0       1       0          1          0
#> 3       1       0          0          1       0       1          1          1
#>   family3 social4 emotional4 cognitive4 family4
#> 1       0       0          1          0       0
#> 2       0       0          1          1       1
#> 3       0       1          0          0       0
```

---

##### old answer:

```r
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
dat <- data.frame(
  gender = c(1,2,1), 
  social = c("1", "2", "3,4"), 
  emotional = c("1,2,4", "3,4", "1,3"), 
  cognitive = c("3", "4", "1,2,3"), 
  family=c("2", "1,2,4", "1")
)
dat <- dat %>% 
  mutate(across(social:family,  ~purrr::map(str_split(.x, ","), as.numeric)))
```

Then, one by one, you can use `unnest()` on the list columns, and pivot them wider using `pivot_wider()` from `tidyr`.

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(obs = row_number()) %>% 
  dplyr::select(obs, everything()) %>% 
  unnest(social) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "social", 
              values_from = "social", 
              values_fn =  function(x)as.numeric(!is.na(x)), 
              names_prefix="social", 
              values_fill=0) %>%
  unnest(emotional) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "emotional", 
              values_from = "emotional", 
              values_fn =  function(x)as.numeric(!is.na(x)), 
              names_prefix="emotional", 
              values_fill=0) %>% 
  unnest(cognitive) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "cognitive", 
              values_from = "cognitive", 
              values_fn =  function(x)as.numeric(!is.na(x)), 
              names_prefix="cognitive", 
              values_fill=0) %>% 
  unnest(family) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "family", 
              values_from = "family", 
              values_fn =  function(x)as.numeric(!is.na(x)), 
              names_prefix="family", 
              values_fill=0)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 17
#>     obs gender social1 social2 social3 social4 emotion…¹ emoti…² emoti…³ emoti…⁴
#>   <int>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1     1      1       1       0       0       0         1       1       1       0
#> 2     2      2       0       1       0       0         0       0       1       1
#> 3     3      1       0       0       1       1         1       0       0       1
#> # … with 7 more variables: cognitive3 <dbl>, cognitive4 <dbl>,
#> #   cognitive1 <dbl>, cognitive2 <dbl>, family2 <dbl>, family1 <dbl>,
#> #   family4 <dbl>, and abbreviated variable names ¹​emotional1, ²​emotional2,
#> #   ³​emotional4, ⁴​emotional3
```

You could also turn the `unnest()` and `pivot_wider()` steps into a function and then just call that function on the data:

```r
u_pivot <- function(.data, x){
  xn <- as_label(enquo(x))
  .data %>% 
    unnest({{ x }}) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from =  xn,
                values_from =  xn,
                values_fn =  function(x)as.numeric(!is.na(x)),
                names_prefix= xn,
                values_fill=0)
}

dat %>% 
  mutate(obs = row_number()) %>% 
  u_pivot(social) %>% 
  u_pivot(emotional) %>% 
  u_pivot(cognitive) %>% 
  u_pivot(family)

#> # A tibble: 3 × 17
#>   gender   obs social1 social2 social3 social4 emotion…¹ emoti…² emoti…³ emoti…⁴
#>    <dbl> <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1      1     1       1       0       0       0         1       1       1       0
#> 2      2     2       0       1       0       0         0       0       1       1
#> 3      1     3       0       0       1       1         1       0       0       1
#> # … with 7 more variables: cognitive3 <dbl>, cognitive4 <dbl>,
#> #   cognitive1 <dbl>, cognitive2 <dbl>, family2 <dbl>, family1 <dbl>,
#> #   family4 <dbl>, and abbreviated variable names ¹​emotional1, ²​emotional2,
#> #   ³​emotional4, ⁴​emotional3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: My answer is quite similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72885469/pivot-wider-a-column-containing-lists) so perhaps it should be considered a duplicate.

Comment: ouch, there must be a better way, maybe using purrr

Comment: @zx8754 challenge accepted - I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A start perhaps. You can use `dplyr::across` to move across multiple columns or all columns. This will require some cleanup afterwards but should get you started.

First some data:

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- tibble(gender=c(1,2),
               social=c(1,'1,2,4'),
               emotional=c(2,'3,4'))
```

Not sure if there is a way to program this so it recognized the number of commas but this adds blanks where there are fewer than the max and you need to hard code the max!

```
data %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = everything(),
                .fns = ~str_split_fixed(.,',',3)))
```

To rename maybe examine this question:
[Splitting multiple string columns and rename the new columns adequately- R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63249873/splitting-multiple-string-columns-and-rename-the-new-columns-adequately-r)

Here's code from the link adapted to this question:

````
pipe_to_do <- . %>%
  str_split_fixed(string = .,pattern = "(,)",n = 3) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  rename(letter = V1,
         number = V2,
         sign = V3)

xx <- data %>%
  summarise(across(everything(),.fns = pipe_to_do))
xx

names_xx <- names(xx)

combine_names <- function(df,name) {
  str_c(name,"_",df)
}

combine_names_func <- function(df,name){
  df %>% 
    rename_with(.fn = ~ combine_names(.x,name))
}

map2(xx,names_xx,combine_names_func) %>% 
  reduce(bind_cols)
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Using *data.table*, reshape the data to a long format - *melt*, then *split* on comma, and reshape it back to wide format - *dcast*:

```
library(data.table)

d <- fread("gender  social  emotional   cognitive   family
1   1   1,2,4   3   2
2   2   3,4 4   1,2,4
1   3,4 1,3 1,2,3   1")

d[, id := .I
  ][, melt(.SD, id.vars = c("id", "gender"), variable.name = "grp")
    ][, .(x = paste(grp, unlist(tstrsplit(value, split = ",")), sep = "_")), by = .(id, gender, grp)
      ][, dcast(.SD, id + gender ~ x, \(i){sum(!is.na(i))}) ]

#    id gender cognitive_1 cognitive_2 cognitive_3 cognitive_4
# 1:  1      1           0           0           1           0
# 2:  2      2           0           0           0           1
# 3:  3      1           1           1           1           0
#    emotional_1 emotional_2 emotional_3 emotional_4 family_1 family_2
# 1:           1           1           0           1        0        1
# 2:           0           0           1           1        1        1
# 3:           1           0           1           0        1        0
#    family_4 social_1 social_2 social_3 social_4
# 1:        0        1        0        0        0
# 2:        1        0        1        0        0
# 3:        0        0        0        1        1
```